# Tabula not converting all PDF pages to CSV in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pdf, tabula

I am trying to convert an entire directory of PDF files to CSV, but my code is only picking up the first page and I need to get all pages in a given PDF.

```
# Convert pdf to csv
path = 'mypath\*.pdf'
for f in glob.glob(path):
    df = tabula.read_pdf(f, pages = 'all')[0]
    df.to_csv(f + '.csv', index = False)
```